# Crystal reports keeps prompting login form on client pc

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

i have been struggling with this problem for a few days now and i cant find a solution.. hopefully someone had this problem before and can help me. So on a client pc recently the crystal report is asking for login credentials. On my developer machine i have no problem even using their database. Im setting the login credentials via code like so:

```
dezeReport.SetDatabaseLogon(strGebruikersnaam, strWachtwoord, csb("Data Source"), csb("Initial Catalog"))
```

like i said on my machine is working, with client database, but on the client pc is not!

Also i found this forum with a fix but i cant seem to find the .dll he is talking about.
The forum is: http://www.xtremedotnettalk.com/showthread.php?t=81509 (Last reply)

Does anyone have a idea on how i can fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Was working and suddenly that happen or never worked? I mean on client's pc.

Comment: was working, and after one update it stop working.. i have checked the queries/ database connection and everything seems ok, on the client side it does not work!

Comment: Maybe is some windows update. But i do not know for sure.

Comment: Pc didnt get any windows updates. On a different client using the same version of our app the report works fine. Same database structure same app version..

Comment: But you said that it was working until one update.

Comment: update from my app(i.e.: 4.3.44.50 to 4.3.44.51) thats the update im talking about not windows update. Sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21709438/3184380

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

To fix this problem i re-imported all the subreports(delete and add again) on my main report and all its working now!

Just cant understand why for some clients it worked and also on my machine and for others was asking for database credentials!

Answer (score -1):

i also solved this problem with another approach..
i set a new datasource for my report using sql oledb as provider(at first i was using sqlcln10 or sqlcln11) then it all worked out fine! btw i'm using sql server 2014