# Why Crystal reports asking for database login credentials?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, crystal-reports

I have read all the question and answer about this question related in stackoverflow.

But i can't get help from these question.

**My code**

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared

Partial Class Reports_LReport
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Public Report As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument()
Public thisConnectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("cnStringMain").ConnectionString
Dim reportDocument As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument = Nothing


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim scriptManager__1 As ScriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Me)
    scriptManager__1.RegisterPostBackControl(Me.FactroyAttendance)

    If Not IsPostBack = True Then

    Else
    LoadReport()
    End If
  End Sub


Protected Sub cmdShow_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles cmdShow.Click
    LoadReport()
End Sub


Private Sub LoadReport()


    If Me.reportDocument IsNot Nothing Then
        Me.reportDocument.Close()
        Me.reportDocument.Dispose()
    End If
    Dim SConn As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("cnStringMain").ConnectionString)
    Dim thisConnection As New SqlConnection(thisConnectionString)
    Dim mySelectCommand As SqlCommand = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("prLeaveStatusReport", thisConnection)
    mySelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    reportDocument = New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument()
    Dim reportPath As String = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/JoyLeaveReport.rpt")
    reportDocument.Load(reportPath)
    Dim connInfo As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo()
    connInfo.ServerName = SConn.DataSource
    connInfo.DatabaseName = SConn.InitialCatalog
    connInfo.UserID = SConn.UserID
    connInfo.Password = SConn.Password
    Dim tableLogOnInfo As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo()
    tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = connInfo
    For Each table As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table In reportDocument.Database.Tables
        table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogOnInfo)
        table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = connInfo.ServerName
        table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = connInfo.DatabaseName
        table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = connInfo.UserID
        table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = connInfo.Password
        table.Location = "dbo." + table.Location
    Next


    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFrom.Text) Then
        reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@dateFrom", "")
    Else
        reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@dateFrom", Convert.ToDateTime(txtFrom.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))

    End If

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmployeeID.Text) Then
        reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@empId", "")
    Else
        reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@empId", txtEmployeeID.Text)
    End If


    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTo.Text) Then
        reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@dateTo", "")
    Else
        reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@dateTo", Convert.ToDateTime(txtTo.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))

    End If

        FactroyAttendance.ReportSource = reportDocument
        FactroyAttendance.DataBind()
        FactroyAttendance.ReportSource = reportDocument
        FactroyAttendance.DataBind()



End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Unload(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If Me.reportDocument IsNot Nothing Then
        Me.reportDocument.Close()
        Me.reportDocument.Dispose()
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

I have a from where i have three fields  1. Fromdate 2. Todate 3. EmployeeId

My reports is working fine but when i am going to export the report in pdf or word it ask me for the value of parameters and database login.

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**
[image]

**Image 3**
[image]

So, i have explained from my site as much as possible.
How could i solve it?
And thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop crystal report viewer from asking login credentials when opening subreport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709438/how-to-stop-crystal-report-viewer-from-asking-login-credentials-when-opening-sub)

Comment: tor matha sala, dekhos na upore ami likhsi je ai question ar related question ase but i am not getting any help.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you put the logon informations right, so the problem could be that you don't cache your crystalreport object.

You'll need to cache your object and bind it again in the Page_Init web method of your webpage. It's necessary when you are going to have multiple page in your report, and when exporting i think.

More informations in this doc : http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/sapCRVS2010/en/crnet13_sp14_dg_en.pdf

Page 56 ( section 1.3.3.4 ) for example.

Comment: i am not getting help. should i create the report once again ?

Comment: You need to cache your crystalreport object, and then in the page init retrieve it and do 
        `FactroyAttendance.ReportSource = reportDocument;
        FactroyAttendance.DataBind();`

Comment: solved :  just adding a method . Here FactoryAttendance is the crystalViewer.  [   Protected Sub .FactroyAttendance_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles FactroyAttendance.Load
        LoadReport()
    End Sub  ]