# Crystal reports for .net prompting login information everytime

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Im using a Dataset class .xsd file which contains schema for 2 tables.  This is a part of a dll which I am adding as a reference to my project.  Iam able to use all the methods from the referenced dll.

While designing the crystal report, for the Datasource, by default this dataset is prompted and I am able to see both the tables under it and from the field explorer i have used the columns from the tables.

I am filling in data into those two tables during  runtime before calling the report. It works perfectly fine.

BUT, when I move my code from one server environment to another, the database login information is prompted everytime I load the report.

Im not using any table from the database.  I don't understand how to make crystal report 'see' the datasource.

I have gone through most help links that talk about this problem, but not one seem to have my kind of environment.  Please advise.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709438/how-to-stop-crystal-report-viewer-from-asking-login-credentials-when-opening-sub)?

Comment: How did you set up your crystal report connection to db? This is very important part. It sometimes we can say you are just collecting data to database by our code but on the other hand we missed up that the crystal report itself need to login too..

Comment: Under Database Expert - Available Datasources - My Connections - I selected this dataset which was already shown there.

Comment: Mr. Adeel, I tried that.  Also removing connection info and adding again.  But in my case iam not using any table from the db.  So where and how should i add the credentials to crystal report is my problem.

Comment: Why don't you try to use odbc connection. everytime you update your project you always do to rebuild  to include your current changes has being made.