# Crystal Subreport prompting for login

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report

When running an app that shows a crystal report that has subreport, the user is prompted for login information.

Below is my code I am using to pass the login information to the report. This code is executed when the form is shown. I have a test vs2017 app that contains a form with a crystal report viewer on it. The login information is passed and works fine until I add a subreport. Once a subreport is added to my existing report the user is prompted to log into the database. Upon entering the correct login credentials, a login failed message appears. The report cannot be run. The report gets data from a command query from the database.

```
    Sections crSections;
    ReportDocument crReportDocument, crSubreportDocument;
    SubreportObject crSubreportObject;
    ReportObjects crReportObjects;
    ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo;
    Database crDatabase;
    Tables crTables;
    TableLogOnInfo crTableLogOnInfo;
    crReportDocument = new ReportDocument();
    crReportDocument.Load(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, CrystalReport3.rpt"));
    crDatabase = crReportDocument.Database;
    crTables = crDatabase.Tables;
    crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
    crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "myservname";
    crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "mydatabasename";
    crConnectionInfo.UserID = "sa";
    crConnectionInfo.Password = "myusername";
    foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table aTable in crTables)
         {
         crTableLogOnInfo = aTable.LogOnInfo;
         crTableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
         aTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogOnInfo);
         }
         // THIS STUFF HERE IS FOR REPORTS HAVING SUBREPORTS 
         // set the sections object to the current report's section 
         crSections = crReportDocument.ReportDefinition.Sections;
         // loop through all the sections to find all the report objects 
         foreach (Section crSection in crSections)
             {
             crReportObjects = crSection.ReportObjects;
             //loop through all the report objects in there to find all 
 subreports 
             foreach (ReportObject crReportObject in crReportObjects)
                 {
                 if (crReportObject.Kind == ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject)
                 {
                     crSubreportObject = (SubreportObject)crReportObject;
                     //open the subreport object and logon as for the general report 
                     crSubreportDocument =                crSubreportObject.OpenSubreport(crSubreportObject.SubreportName);
                     crDatabase = crSubreportDocument.Database;
                     crTables = crDatabase.Tables;
                     foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table aaTable in crTables)
                     {
                         crTableLogOnInfo = aaTable.LogOnInfo;
                         crTableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
                         aaTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogOnInfo);
                     }
                 }
            }
         }
    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crReportDocument;
    crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

I expect the report to be run without prompting the user as I am passing in login credentials.

Comment: Please check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709438/how-to-stop-crystal-report-viewer-from-asking-login-credentials-when-opening-sub

Comment: Please, post a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and format your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Link](http://https%20://www.ebay.com/itm/372653783446)

**Code:**

```
Sections crSections; 
ReportDocument crReportDocument, crSubreportDocument; 
SubreportObject crSubreportObject;
ReportObjects crReportObjects; 
ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo; 
Database crDatabase; 
Tables crTables; 
TableLogOnInfo crTableLogOnInfo; 
crReportDocument = new ReportDocument();
crReportDocument.Load("c:\\reports\\Homes.rpt",CrystalDecisions.Shared.
OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByTempCopy); 
crDatabase = crReportDocument.Database; 
crTables = crDatabase.Tables; 
crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(); 
crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "DSNName Or Server Name"; 
crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "HopeAndHome";
crConnectionInfo.UserID = "sa"; 
crConnectionInfo.Password = "password"; 
foreach (Section crSection in crSections)
{
    crReportObjects = crSection.ReportObjects;
    //loop through all the report objects in there to find all subreports 
    foreach (ReportObject crReportObject in crReportObjects)
    {
        if (crReportObject.Kind == ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject)
        {
            crSubreportObject = (SubreportObject)crReportObject;
            //open the subreport object and logon as for the general report 
            crSubreportDocument = crSubreportObject.OpenSubreport(crSubreportObject.SubreportName);
            crDatabase = crSubreportDocument.Database;
            crTables = crDatabase.Tables;
            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table aTable in crTables)
            {
                crTableLogOnInfo = aTable.LogOnInfo;
                crTableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
                aTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogOnInfo);
            }
        }
    }
}
```